# Is kill -15 the same as File -> Quit?

Tags: terminal

I want to quit a process but without force quitting it. Is that possible from the terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`kill` acts on Unix level, the targeted process is free to ignore any signal besides `kill -9`. And depending on the internal structure of the process you are looking at, `kill -15` will not be the same as 'File->Quit'.

As an alternative you could do something like `osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to quit'`.